# create cookie fo other applications

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Assume we have three different ASP.NET web applications in our intranet, that all of them have a login page and after authenticating user create a cookie for authenticated user.
Is it available to have one page as a login page and create that three application's cookie from here and then redirect user to demanded application?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. What you need is to redirect loginattempts from all three applications to the same loginpage with a return URL as a parameter so that the loginpage can redirect the user back to the page they were looking for.

There are some requirements that you have to fulfill:

- All three applications need to be on the same domain
- All three applications need to share the same MachineKey

What this will do is create a logincookie that can be decrypted on all three pages.

Comment: thanks
i have to use one cookie file for all three application or it can be separated for each them?

Comment: It would be the same cookie that is given out at the loginpage, but each application can add the data they need to the cookie afterwards.